# how to remove "become a vendor" button from dokan?

Tags: wordpress, dokan

i have a problem with dokan plugin. I want to remove "become a vendor" button from dokan profile (existing solution on wedevs not worked) anybody can help me?

Comment: You can use this blog post- https://nayemdevs.com/how-to-hide-become-a-vendor-button/

Comment: You can remove the become a vendor button by adding this code to your theme functions.php file-
`remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_my_account', array( Dokan_Pro::init(), 'dokan_account_migration_button' ) ); `

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the become a vendor button by adding this code to your theme functions.php file-
`remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_my_account', array( Dokan_Pro::init(), 'dokan_account_migration_button' ) );`

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the button also display:none !important through customize css 
and now one can click on button

2nd method is go to template file and remove that shortcode from there

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_become_a_vendor_button() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_my_account', [ dokan()- 
>frontend_manager->become_a_vendor, 'render_become_a_vendor_section' 
] );
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_become_a_vendor_button' );
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**